# TypeError: 'ListNode' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, list, typeerror

[**This is a problem i came across in leetcode.**](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/)
You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4] Output: [7,0,8] Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.

**this is the program ive written**

```
class Solution(object):
def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
"""
:type l1: ListNode
:type l2: ListNode
:rtype: ListNode
"""
r1=l1[::-1]m
r2=l2[::-1]
s1=[str(i) for i in r1]
digit1=int(''.join(s1))
s2=[str(j) for j in r2]
digit2=int(''.join(s2))
output=[ int(i) for i in str(digit1+digit2)]
output=output[::-1]
return output
print(Solution().addTwoNumbers([2, 4, 3], [5, 6, 4]))
```

[**I am getting the answer in pycharm.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/945Vd.png)
but in leet code, I am getting this error..

```
Runtime Error

TypeError: 'ListNode' object has no attribute '__getitem__' r1=l1[::-1] Line 8 in addTwoNumbers (Solution.py) ret = Solution().addTwoNumbers(param_1, param_2) Line 42 in _driver (Solution.py) _driver() Line 52 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

What is the mistake here and how can i solve it?

Comment: You use a list in pycharm but a linked list is something different. The relevant code of `ListNode` is shown (commented out) when submitting your code to Leetcode.

Comment: So what should i do now?

Comment: First you need to understand what a linked list is. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) can be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem mentions the lists are "linked list" , which are a little different from normal list.

the error occurs when you try to reverse the linked list by slicing technique.

You can reverse a linked list with either a recursive or iterative approach.

Comment: Please update your question to include the code needed to implement your answer. Thanks.